# How to make a request to the database for integration testing in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: spring, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, integration-testing

When compiling a spring boot project, integration tests are performed with requests to an external database, but a connection error occurs in Jenkins at the compilation stage. How do I set up a database connection?
The screenshots show an error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcee4.png)

Comment: You need ensure your jenkins node can connect to the target database server in advance.

Comment: It may also be a network firewall that's blocking TCP/IP connection.